# Fetching Shared Preferences String Value in Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I want to fetch String value from shared preferences and show it in Recylerview Adapter. Any help will be appreciated
This is my code

```
public  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   // private SharedPreferences prefs;
```

public Context context;

```
public ABCAdapter(List<ChatHistory>MessagesList,Context context) {

    this.MessageList = MessagesList;
    context=this.context;


}

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);


       // SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        //String profile_name = pref.getString("profile_name", null);

       prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ipAdrs=prefs.getString("profile_name", "");
 }
}
```

profile_name is already stored in shared preferences.

here I am getting this error.

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null`

Comment: `context` is null here .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: how are you calling ABCAdapter? . You need to pass activity context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
public ABCAdapter(List<ChatHistory>MessagesList,Context context) {

    this.MessageList = MessagesList;
    context=this.context;
}
```

should be:

```
public ABCAdapter(List<ChatHistory>MessagesList,Context context) {

    this.MessageList = MessagesList;
    this.context=context;   //this refers to class variable
}
```

Make sure to pass the activity context while creating the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

A much more easier(and better way) would be

```
itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ipAdrs=prefs.getString("profile_name", "");
```

Also passing the `Context` to `ViewHolder` it is a very bad practice. You can get the `Context` whenever you need from any `View`

Answer (score 0):

you should pass SharedPreferences object to adapter Constructor and read data from it

Comment: no you are passing the context you should create SharedPreferences in activity and pass SharedPreferences instance

Comment: @PooryaTaghizade why should he pass SharedPreferences when he can get the String he needs and pass it directly ?

Comment: @MONK because he need get data for each viewholder base item property.i guess

Comment: @PooryaTaghizade he's always getting the same string `prefs.getString("profile_name", "");`